# MariaDB returns empty set when filtering by a datetime field on a 'view' table, while MySQL (and base view sql ) works fine

Tags: datetime, view, mariadb

first question here so sorry if not good explained.

I have several views on my db for easier selects with multiple table joins, those views have a date_registered (datetime) field, but when I use WHERE on those fields it always returns empty set.

I'm using MariaDB 10.1.48 (latest one on ubuntu 18.04 repos), same tests on MySQL 5.7 works fine.

Easier to see with examples:

**sample data**

```
select id, date_registered from v_tracking limit 5;
+-------+---------------------+
| id    | date_registered     |
+-------+---------------------+
| 13258 | 2021-10-20 12:56:28 |
| 13257 | 2021-10-20 12:51:37 |
| 13256 | 2021-10-20 12:51:37 |
| 13255 | 2021-10-20 12:46:13 |
| 13254 | 2021-10-20 12:42:13 |
+-------+---------------------+
```

**simple select with where date_registered > 'xxxx-xx-xx'**

```
select id, date_registered from v_tracking where date_registered > '2021-10-01' limit 5;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

**filter with other fields works**

```
select id, date_registered from v_tracking where id_company = 6 limit 5;
+-------+---------------------+
| id    | date_registered     |
+-------+---------------------+
| 13227 | 2021-10-20 06:52:13 |
| 13226 | 2021-10-20 06:43:22 |
| 13225 | 2021-10-20 06:43:04 |
| 13224 | 2021-10-20 06:37:12 |
| 13223 | 2021-10-20 06:23:23 |
+-------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And now the craziest part

**adding an 'order by' works**

```
select id, date_registered from v_tracking where date_registered > '2021-10-01' order by id desc limit 5;
+-------+---------------------+
| id    | date_registered     |
+-------+---------------------+
| 13258 | 2021-10-20 12:56:28 |
| 13257 | 2021-10-20 12:51:37 |
| 13256 | 2021-10-20 12:51:37 |
| 13255 | 2021-10-20 12:46:13 |
| 13254 | 2021-10-20 12:42:13 |
+-------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**and forcing conversion to date/timestamp too, but that would probably skip indexes**

```
select id, date_registered from v_tracking where timestamp(date_registered) > '2021-10-01' limit 5;
+-------+---------------------+
| id    | date_registered     |
+-------+---------------------+
| 13258 | 2021-10-20 12:56:28 |
| 13257 | 2021-10-20 12:51:37 |
| 13256 | 2021-10-20 12:51:37 |
| 13255 | 2021-10-20 12:46:13 |
| 13254 | 2021-10-20 12:42:13 |
+-------+---------------------+
```

**but not other way**

```
select id, date_registered from v_tracking where date_registered > timestamp('2021-10-01')  limit 5;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

Tried using 'xxxx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx' too, but same results, also thought that maybe there's a problem in using the date as a string (though I've had no problems with that before), but using where date_registered < now() also returns empty set.

If I use 'show create view v_tracking' to copy the whole SQL (with all joins and so) and add a where date_registered > 'xxxx-xx-xx' to run it (instead of using the view) it works too

WTF am i missing here??

and yes, date_registered is a datetime field

```
desc v_tracking;
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id                     | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |       |
..... 
| date_registered        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: What is the ouput of `show create view v_tracking`?

Comment: How about to test this against an actual MariaDB Server version? 10.1 reached end of life time.

Comment: @slaakso don't want to add the whole query here but it's just a join with multiple (tracking, users, companies...) tables

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`xxxx`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `v_tracking` AS select `tracking`.`id` AS `id`, `companies`.`id` AS `id_company`, ..... `tracking`.`date_registered` AS `date_registered` FROM tracking join companies join .... order by `tracking`.`date_registered` desc,`tracking`.`id` desc
```

As said before, running this whole query with the where date_registered < '...' works fine

Comment: @GeorgRichter I didn't want to mess with external repos on that system, but will probably have to give it a try, I'll let you know if it works

Comment: What if you remove the `order by` from the view's definition? Usually views do not have this as different queries might have different ordering criteria and therefore the extra `order by` just slows things down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging I ended up upgrading MariaDB version to a recent one, and the problem was solved.